# Después de actualizar conda, python da un error "VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, conda

Utilizando la versión de **anaconda de python 3.5 para windows**, después de actualizar algunos paquetes de conda el intérprete python deja de funcionar dando un error

> "The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

A veces este error se produce en algún entorno virtual, siempre con python 3.5. Forzando a bajar la versión de python 3.5 a 3.4 desaparece el problema:

```
C:\> conda install -n myenv python=3.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTA**: este bug está registrado como: [issue #443](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/443)

---

El problema se origina al actualizar el paquete windows `msvc_runtime`, que debería ir acompañado de las *DLLs* necesarias para su funcionamiento.

Si nos fijamos en la lista de versiones de `msvc_runtime`:

```
C:\>conda search msvc_runtime
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ......
msvc_runtime   1.0.0   vc10_0  defaults [vc10]
               1.0.0   vc14_0  defaults [vc14]
               1.0.0    vc9_0  defaults [vc9]
            .  1.0.1        0  defaults
               1.0.1   vc10_0  defaults [vc10]
            *  1.0.1   vc14_0  defaults [vc14]
               1.0.1    vc9_0  defaults [vc9]
```

Tenemos dos versiones, `1.0.0` y `1.0.1`, con distintas etiquetas de compilación según la versión de Visual C++ utilizado. Por defecto, se actualiza a la versión más reciente, la `1.0.1` sin etiqueta, que consiste en un paquete vacío (*transaccional*), sin DLLs asociadas. Este comportamiento puede ser el deseado para un sistema de desarrollo donde se tengan instaladas las librerías de Visual C++; pero en el caso de un usuario normal, va a necesitar instalar estas librería por su cuenta. Si no se tiene cuidado, `conda` puede dejar inoperativo el sistema después de actualizar el paquete `msvc_runtime`, tal vez como dependencia de otro paquete.

Lo recomendable es forzar la versión del paquete `msvc_runtime` (*"pinning"*) para lo que hay que crear un fichero llamado `pinned` en el directorio `conda-meta` de la instalación de conda que contenga la siguiente línea:

```
msvc_runtime 1.0.1 vc14_0
```

De esta manera aseguramos que se instalará la versión `1.0.1` de `msvc_runtime` con las DLLs de *Visual C++-14*. Este *pinning* no debería influir en los paquetes dependientes de `msvc_runtime` puesto que se trata del mismo paquete, únicamente con las DLLs runtime añadidas.

(Documentación sobre [pinning en conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/faq.html#pinning-packages))

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**: después de estudiar el problema en el [registro de bugs](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/443), se decidió eliminar el paquete sin DLLs del repositorio, por lo que *conda* selecciona ahora correctamente el paquete que corresponde con la instalación de python.